# Autocomplete with label, not value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to add an autocomplete field with jquery-ui. I have a list of objects with values and labels, and I want that when the user selects an item, the value goes of an hidden field and the label is in the autocomplete field. But the documentation says "The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item".

Can this behaviour be changed? I think it's more user-friendly if the label is displayed, not the value itself.

Comment: I could go with a setTimeout in the select function, it works, but maybe there is a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on `select` field: using `ui` as argument, you can use `ui.item.label` and `ui.item.value` to do the magic.
Use `preventDefault()` to block the predefined jQuery behavior.

```
$('#your_element').autocomplete({
  // [...]    
  select: function(e,ui){
    e.preventDefault();
    // set value in your element
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    // set value in the hidden field
    $('#hidden').val(ui.item.value);
  },
  // [...]    
});
```